# Audio Web API record MediaStreamSource to AudioNode for Looping

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm currently developing a web based loop station (like the Boss RC-505)

Current situation:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
audioContext = new AudioContext()

let mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
let inputgain = audioContext.createGain()
let outputgain = audioContext.createGain()

mediaStreamSource.connect(inputgain)
inputgain.connect(outputgain)
outputgain.connect(audioContext.destination)
```

After I initialized microphone input (with the users permission), I create a new audioContext.
From this I create the MediaStreamSource, which I feed with my microphones input).
Next in line are two GainNodes, which are used for input and output of the audio stream.
then there is the destination, which is just the speaker output.

In between of the inputgain and outputgain, I now want to have an audio node, which records from the mediaStreamSource on a given time (onclick event) and also stop recording on a given time.
After it's recorded it should just keep looping.

I couldn't find anything useful online, so I hope someone here has an answer to my question.
For visualizing on what I'm working on, this is the web-app in developing: 
https://corsiin.github.io/LoopToGo/